# .Net Core project.json multiple projects with the same name

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have project named Common placed in directory NamespaceA.
I have project named Common placed in directory NamespaceB.

Now I want to reference first project inside second using project.json

But it is not possible!

```
error: Cycle detected: 
error:   Common (>= 9.0.0) -> Common (>= 9.0.0) -> Common (>= 9.0.0).
```

VS thinks that both are the same project!

Comment: Can't you just rename the projects, possibly by specifying [`"name"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#name) in your project.json?

Comment: It looks the single way is to really rename projects. For example Core.Common, Something.Common. I tried to specify name attribute for project and reference by new name. But there was an error: Unable to resolve 'Core.Common2 (>= 9.0.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'. VS intellisense does not show "name" as option for project.json. So it allows to specify title only and assembly name in buildOptions. I do not know exactly but it can be deprecated already or not yet supported well.

Comment: `"name"` belongs at the top level of project.json, not inside `"buildOptions"`.

Comment: I told about assembly name only in buildOptions... title as well is root element... you have read my comment not very carefully... ))

Answer (score 2):

In `project.json` you reference NuGet packages. If you have multiple NuGet packages with the same, then the project system cannot figure out which one is which. So, unfortunately, your scenario is not supported. The only solution is to rename the packages.

It's almost like having two types with the same name, both imported and referencing them without the full name. The compiler will not know which to pick.

Comment: You assume that project.json references only nuget packages and not projects in solution... I guess you will agree that in most cases project in solution is not equal to a nuget package. Nuget package can contain multiple assemblies inside. So Net Core tries to make all universally but with disadvantages in comparison with csproj system where I can have projects named the same. And .Net Core team removed name element for performance reason... so I cannot use it. Additional disadvantage is absence of extern aliases.